# Native view inside Phonegap/Cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordovawebview

I was wondering if there is any way to embed native view inside phonegap app.
I'm aware of CordovaWebView but it embeds cordova view inside native app and I need it vise versa:

http://s10.postimg.org/4681ufp39/PHONEGAP_NATIVE.png

Thanks

Comment: have you used inAppBrowser plugin?? I think you're asking for that concept. You'll need to build custom plugin.

Comment: not possible, you can put a native view over the phonegap view, but not inside